# how to apply pca in matlab?

Tags: matlab, pca

there is a matrix of 5100*720 dimension. each class includes 2550 sample. each row represents a sample of the classes. the pca is applied on each class. the problem is the output matrix is a 720*720. the question is in the output matrix which dimension represents the class samples? or which dimension must be assumed as the classes?
thanks

coeffs = pca(P300)

Comment: well it toatally depens on how the pca is calculated. if it's an embedded function you have to read if the rows or the columns of the output represent the PC's However I dont know why the shape of output is a problem. The output of PCA for a matrix of shape mxn is always (ixi | i = min(m,n)). you can not get PC's on the higher dimension which has to do with Correlation matrix.you have 720 dimensions in your feauture space. thats why you can only have 720 orthogonal eigen vectors.

Comment: yes. you are right. but now the rows are the classes and columns are the principle components?

Comment: you don't have classes in PCA. PCA doesn't understand class. you have number of samples x feautures. In the next step you use a classification algorithm (SVM, NN, ...) to classify the samples. If you have labels you can use supervised algorthms . It is important to understand that PCA only finds the eigenvectors (the direction of variances of data) and the eigenvalues (their intensities) and that it fully works independent on the classes of data. That's why the output of PCA doesn't say anything about classes.

Comment: aha. thank you. so i have another class which has same size. based on it after applying pca i have features of a class as a 720*720 matrix and another class as same. now i want to classify these classes i must label each row. is it true?

Comment: If all of your data, on which youre applying PCA are in one class yes.